# How to use Passport.js with Prisma

Tags: express, passport.js, prisma

I'm following the tutorials from *theodinproject* right now and I'm having trouble with the user authentication. In the tutorials, they used `Mongodb` with `Mongoose` to integrate with `Passport.js` but in my case, I use `Postgres` with `Prisma` to integrate with the `Passport.js` so the code will be a little bit different. I checked both *theodinproject* and doc from `Passport.js`  one uses `Mongoose` and one uses raw SQL code. So I don't know how to do it with `Prisma`. I tried to do some research to see if anyone has done this before but I don't see many results for that.

I tried to type something to play along with it and comes up with the code below

```
passport.use(async (username, password, done) => {
  const user = await prisma.user.findFirst(
    { where: { username } },
    (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" });
      }
      if (user.password !== password) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    }
  );
});
```

Clearly, it's wrong (because the app crashed) but I don't know how to fix that. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance :)

Edit:
I've encountered another problem with `deserializeUser` according to *theodinproject* this is their code:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

How can I do it the *Prisma way*? I tried to code it myself but I'm stuck here:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({ where: { id } });
});
```

And for the `serializeUser` I'm not sure if I did it right

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```js
passport.use(async (username, password, done) => {
  const user = await prisma.user.findFirst(
    { where: { username } },
  );

  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" });
  }
  if (user.password !== password) {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
  }
  return done(null, user);
});
```

`findFirst` takes only one parameter

If you really want to catch a possible error, something that shouldn't happen unless your database is down maybe, you can do

```js
passport.use(async (username, password, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst(
      { where: { username } },
    );

    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" });
    }
    if (user.password !== password) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    return done(err);
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Your `serializeUser` function looks good and for `deserializeUser`, we need to do the same as the `use` function

```js
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    // You did well where
    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({ where: { id } });

    done(null, user)
  } catch (error) {
    done(error)
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for helping me with that, but I've encountered another problem with `deserializeUser`(I edited the question above to make it easier to read). Do you know how to fix it by any chance? Thank you very much.

Comment: You were on the right track, have a good day